# Porting my existing java project on Netbeans to another machine and then running it gives a UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I started coding for a client-server machine on java, using RMI(Remote Method Invocation). The code works fine on my machine. It basically gives commands to the client machine and the client processes these commands and responds accordingly. After executing the command, the machine sends back its status to the server. An example would be, the server requests for an image feed from the client and the client returns an image to the server.

I used git to clone the current project and push it to another machine. When I execute the client side code, it works completely fine and the other machine(to which I pushed the source) responds the way it should.

However, when I run the server side code to code on the other machine, it gives a cryptic error that says:

```
C:\Users\RdX\Desktop\Thiswa
javax.naming.NamingException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in          server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javadrone/Server (Unsupported major.minor   version 51.0)]
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:159)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:249)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
at javadrone.server.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:46)
at javadrone.server.DroneServer.<init>(DroneServer.java:45)
at javadrone.server.DroneServer.main(DroneServer.java:84)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javadrone/Server (Unsupported major.minor    version 51.0)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:349)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:207)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:144)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:460)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:701)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
at     sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)
...5 more
```

On inspecting the stack trace, the code that generates the exception is:

```
package javadrone.server;


import javadrone.Drone;
import javadrone.Server;

import javadrone.command.CommandQueue;


import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public abstract class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Server {
public static final String            RMI_PROT = "rmi:";
private static Context                namingContext;
private static HashMap<String, Drone> registeredDrones;
private String                        name;

public ServerImpl(String name) throws RemoteException, NamingException {
    this.name     = name;
    namingContext = new InitialContext();
    namingContext.rebind(RMI_PROT + name, ServerImpl.this);
    registeredDrones = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public String getName() throws RemoteException {
    return name;
}

@Override
public Drone registerDrone(String droneName) throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Remote client registered...");

    DroneImpl d = new DroneImpl(new CommandQueue(), droneName);

    registeredDrones.put(droneName, d);
    hasRegistered(d);

    return d;
}

public Drone getDrone(String droneName) {
    return registeredDrones.get(droneName);
}

@Override
public long getTime() throws RemoteException {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public abstract void hasRegistered(DroneImpl d);
}
```

To be specific,

```
namingContext.rebind(RMI_PROT + name, ServerImpl.this)
```

is the line that generates the error.

I searched a lot of places and they say that when the JDK compliler is of a higher version than the JRE version, it may produce such an error.

However I uninstalled all prior JDKs and JREs and recompiled the code after installing JDK 7.03. It still gives the same exception.

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Comment: The complete project is here: https://code.google.com/p/intelli-drone/source/browse/#git%253Fstate%253Dclosed , if you want further information.

Answer (score 0):

You may *think* you've removed all the other JDKs and JREs, but I strongly suspect you haven't really.

You haven't said how you're running the server code, but I suggest you log `System.getProperty("java.version")` as early as you can - I'm sure you'll find you're using an earlier JRE than you think you are.

Classfile version 51.0 is Java 7, which makes sense if you compiled it with JDK 7. It's just what you're using to *run* the code which is the problem.

If you're just running:

```
java ...
```

from the command line, I suggest you try *explicitly* running a particular version of Java, including the full path to the executable.

Comment: I inspected the registry and under the HKEY_LOCALMACHINE/SOFTWARES/JavaSoft section and compared it to my other machine, the entries completely match. The server code runs through the rmiregistry (If that's what you're asking). The client connects to the server by explicitly supplying the IP address (It actually scans for all IPs in it's own subnet and finds potential candidates).

Comment: @javajava: Registry entries aside, it's clearly *not* running Java 7. What the client does is irrelevant - it's only how the server is started that's important here. Which version of rmiregistry did you run?